# MVC - Unable to get data from model on Ajax call

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, model

I have tried many things as you will see in my commented out code.  What is working (sorta - gets to the controller but no data) is what's not commented out.  I am getting to my controller but all the data is 0.  I need to pass in the entire ViewModel as it has a lot of fields in it.  Thanks in advance

Here is my Ajax that's not working:

```
function summaryrpt() {     
    //alert('dd');
    //var JsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model))';
    //var summmodel = JSON.parse(JsonModel);
    //var jsonInput = @Model; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //data: { model = JSON.stringify(summmodel) },
        //data: JsonModel = JSON.stringify(JsonModel) ,
        //data: { JsonModel: JSON.stringify(@Model) },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model))',
        //data: { jsonInput: JSON.stringify(@Model) }',
        //url: '@Url.Action("ApproveSummaryReport", "Home")',
         url: '/Home/ApproveSummaryReport'
        
    }).done(function (res) {
        //alert('done');
    });            
}
```

Controller Method signature

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ApproveSummaryReport(SummaryViewModel model)
```

See my commented out code for what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to pass the model so here i am passing 2 of the 200 parms so others can see what i did.

```
var jsonInput = {
AccRatioBCHFullCommMulPer: $('#AccRatioBCHFullCommMulPer').val(),
AccRatioBCHFullHO: $('#AccRatioBCHFullHO').val()
};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: { jsonInput: JSON.stringify(jsonInput) },                
   url: '/Home/ApproveSummaryReport'
}).done(function (res) {
 //alert('done');
});
```